# Selenium Server with Internet Explorer 9 TypeKey not working

Tags: selenium, internet-explorer-9

i'm learning how to use Selenium and have used the Selenium IDE to create a test suite in Firefox.  I'm now learning how to execute the same test suite in Selenium Server that was created with the IDE.

My problem is that one of the test cases using the "TypeKeys" is not being executed in Internet Explorer 9.  Does anyone know how I can solve this issue?  Searching on StackOF hasn't lead to anything nor google.

Thanks!

Comment: Did you try typeValue? and which version of selenium are you using?